# Catalina now only saves pdf's from print box to preview not the folder I choose

Tags: ms-office, pdf, preview, printing

I use Excel spreadsheets everyday and use the pdf print facility to send them to clients suppliers and for many other uses. Catalina now will not save the pdf's to any other folder than the preview folder which is annoying and wastes my time having to move them to the folders I need to keep them in. How can I change this or do I have to roll back the installation to Sierra?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what steps you take? I can use "Save As PDF" from the Print dialog in Excel 2016, and I get a file dialog where I can select any location. I can also use Save As ... PDF. Also, what/where is "the preview folder"?

Comment: Exactly the same as I have always used in the print facility choose pdf and a box loads to select the location but it now misses this and just downloads it to the preview folder

Comment: It says that it has saved but it hasn't saved to my selected folder

Comment: Where is "the preview folder"? Does any other app do the same thing? Word? TextEdit? Have you restarted?